Analogies Between Electrical Circuits and Complex Analysis
I've been working on drawing analogies between electrical circuits and complex analysis, inspired by the resemblance between Kirchhoff's laws and properties of holomorphic functions. Specifically, I have developed several theorems in electrical circuits that are analogous to those in complex analysis. I would like to know if there are any existing studies or research on this topic and if there are any additional theorems that could be considered within this framework.
Theoretical Framework
Consider a holomorphic function
$ f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y). $
By the Cauchy-Riemann equations, the vector field
$ \mathbf{F} = (u, -v) $
is both divergence-free and curl-free. Reflecting on this, Kirchhoff's current law (KCL) resembles being divergence-free, and Kirchhoff's voltage law (KVL) resembles being curl-free. This led me to think that an electrical circuit is like a discrete version of complex analysis. Here are some theorems I have developed.
Definitions
Definition: An electrical circuit is a connected graph with a finite number of vertices. Each edge in the graph has a non-zero resistance. The vertices of the electrical circuit can be divided into 'internal nodes', denoted as $a_1, a_2, \cdots , a_m$, and 'boundary nodes', denoted as $b_1, b_2, \cdots , b_n$. Internal nodes are ordinary vertices, while a boundary node $b_k$ is grounded with a potential $V(b_k)$. Let $R(i, j)$ denote the resistance of the edge connecting nodes $i$ and $j$. Define $N(i) = \{j:$ an edge exists connecting nodes $i$ and $j\}$. The potential at node $i$ is written as $V(i)$, and the current flowing from node $i$to $j$ is written as $I(i, j)$.
Theorems

Mean Value Property:
$
   V(a_i) = \frac{\sum_{j\in N(a_i)} R(j, a_i)^{-1}\cdot V(j) }{\sum_{j\in N(a_i)} R(j, a_i) ^{-1}}.
   $
Proof: By Kirchhoff's current law,
$
   \sum_{j\in N(a_i)} I(a_i, j) = 0,
   $
and by Ohm's law,
$
   I(a_i, j) = \frac{V(a_i) - V(j)}{R(a_i, j)}.
   $
Thus,
$
   \sum_{j\in N(a_i)} \frac{V(a_i) - V(j)}{R(a_i, j)} = 0.
   $
Rearranging this equation, we get
$
   V(a_i) = \frac{\sum_{j\in N(a_i)} R(j, a_i)^{-1}\cdot V(j) }{\sum_{j\in N(a_i)} R(j, a_i) ^{-1}}.
   $

Maximum Modulus Principle:
There does not exist an internal node $a_i$ such that $V(a_i)>[<]V(j)$ for all $j\in N(a_i)$. (The maximum [minimum] potential among all nodes is the same as the maximum [minimum] potential among the boundary nodes.)
Proof: If there exists an internal node $a_i$ such that $V(a_i)>[<]V(j)$ for all $j\in N(a_i)$, then
$
   V(a_i) >[<] \frac{\sum_{j\in N(a_i)} R(j, a_i)^{-1}\cdot V(j) }{\sum_{j\in N(a_i)} R(j, a_i) ^{-1}},
   $
which contradicts the Mean Value Property.

Liouville's Theorem:
If the electrical circuit has no boundary nodes, then all nodes have the same potential.
Proof: Since the number of nodes is finite, there exists a node $i_1$ with the maximum potential. Since $V(i_1)$ is the maximum, for all $i_2\in N(i_1)$, $V(i_1)\geq V(i_2)$. Thus,
$
   V(i_1) \geq \frac{\sum_{i_2\in N(i_1)} R(i_2, i_1)^{-1}\cdot V(i_2) }{\sum_{i_2 \in N(i_1)} R(i_2, i_1) ^{-1}},
   $
but by the Mean Value Property,
$
   V(i_1) = \frac{\sum_{i_2\in N(i_1)} R(i_2, i_1)^{-1}\cdot V(i_2) }{\sum_{i_2 \in N(i_1)} R(i_2, i_1) ^{-1}}.
   $
The equality condition for
$
   V(i_1) \geq \frac{\sum_{i_2\in N(i_1)} R(i_2, i_1)^{-1}\cdot V(i_2) }{\sum_{i_2 \in N(i_1)} R(i_2, i_1) ^{-1}}
   $
is that $V(i_1) = V(i_2)$ for all $i_2\in N(i_1)$.
Since $V(i_2)$ also has the maximum potential, the same argument applies to $i_2$, showing that $V(i_2) = V(i_3)$ for all $i_3\in N(i_2)$.
Repeating this process, since the electrical circuit is a connected graph, we conclude that all nodes have the same potential.

Node Analysis (Corollary):
Using Kirchhoff's current law for all internal nodes $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_m$, we get a system of $m$ linear equations. Considering $V(a_1), V(a_2), \cdots V(a_m)$ as unknowns and $V(b_1), V(b_2), \cdots V(b_n)$ as constants, this is a system of $m$ equations with $m$ unknowns. If $n=0$, the solution to this system is $V(a_1)=V(a_2)=\cdots =V(a_m)$, and if $n>0$, the system has a unique solution.
Proof: The case $n=0$ follows from Liouville's Theorem.
Consider the case $n>0$.
The system
$
   \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{b}
   $
has a unique solution if and only if
$
   \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{0}
   $
has only the trivial solution.
To show that the system of equations has only the trivial solution when all boundary nodes are grounded (their potentials are zero), note that by the Maximum Modulus Principle, the maximum and minimum potentials among the internal nodes are both zero, proving that the only solution is the trivial one.


Questions

Existing Research: Are there any known studies or prior research exploring the analogy between electrical circuits and complex analysis like I did? Since I am an undergraduate student, I have no experience of writing a paper. I wonder whether if my idea is novel or not.
Further Theorems: Given the established analogies and theorems above, are there other theorems in complex analysis that might have analogous counterparts in the context of electrical circuits? Any suggestions for further exploration would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your insights and suggestions!

John Baez did some stuff along these lines, here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kirchhoff%27s+laws

One point to note with Baez's work is the use of the Laplace transform. This allows him to incorporate inductors and capacitors using complex numbers rather than differential equations.

Expressing impedance as a complex number is the most obvious example that comes to my mind. All of control systems topics in electrical engineering builds on complex numbers, pole zero analysis etc. And most of communication related electrical engineering is based on Fourier transform, which directly is a complex variable application
